# Dynamically look for connected drop lists with Angular CDK drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have an HTML element with a mouseenter listener that shows a hidden [cdk drop list](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList) on mouseenter (with *ngIf). When on drag start of a [cdk drag item](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag), I'm getting the warning `CdkDropList could not find connected drop list with id "xxxx"`.

This is most likely because the hidden drop list doesn't exist in the DOM yet. I would like to know if there's a way to dynamically look for droplists in the DOM, so when dragging over my element, it picks up the hidden droplist and allows me to drag and drop there.

Comment: Try use `[style.display]="condition?'none':null` instead a *ngIf. NOTE: It's only an idea, without important part of your code it's impossible help you more

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.